# "Dim client As New RestSharp.RestClient" not working

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019, .net-3.5, restsharp

I have a VB.Net ClassLibrary project in VS 2019 and .Net Framework 3.5. The project has a reference to RestSharp. I then reference my class library project in a Windows Forms Application .NET Framework 3.5 app.

In the library, I have this code:

```
Dim client As New RestSharp.RestClient With {.BaseUrl = New Uri(IQProURL + "api/vault/" + id)}
```

does not throw an error, but also the below code with `client` is not able to generate a response:

```
Dim response = client.Execute(request)
```

However, if I reference my same class library using a Windows Application with .NET Core 3.1, everything works fine.

I am expecting a Json object as the response. I need to use this with the .NET Framework 3.5 app. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

.NET Framework 3.5 reached the end of life a long time ago, and it's no longer supported by RestSharp. You need to visit NuGet.org and find the version of RestSharp that is compatible with .NET Framework 3.5. You need to be aware that neither .NET Framework 3.5, nor old versions of RestSharp receive any security patches or any other fixes.

Comment: I was using RestSharp.Net20 Version 105.2.3.0 which required Newtonsoft.Json Version 13.0.0.0 with the Framework 3.5 Class.  It worked fine if the client was a .Core 3.1
So I've changed the Class to Framework 4.5 and am now searching for a RestSharp that will work with it. 
I don't know what the latest version of RestSharp is.

Answer (score -2):

Thank you for that info about Fw 3.5
I was able to change the ClassLibrary to Fw 4.5 and the Windows Forms Application to Fw 4.5.  I did find a combination of RestSharp and NewtonSoft.Json to work with Fw 4.5.
Under this configuration, on the dev computer the Windows Forms Application was able to dim a RestSharp client and a RestSharp responce all the way through deserializeing the Json object.  That was a great thing to see.  The Windows Forms Application will not run on XP now but I'm just going to tell the users to run it on Win10 or better and forget XP on this option.
Next I ran the Windows Forms Application on a Win10 system by accessing it on dev computer in WindowsApp1\bin\Release the through the LAN.  It did run, BUT it displayed the same inability to get RestSharp to dim a client.
These are the files in the WindowsApp1\bin\Release directory.

```
 - ClassLibrary1.dll 
 - ClassLibrary1.pdb 
 - ClassLibrary1.xml
 - Newtonsoft.Json.dll 
 - Newtonsoft.Json.xml 
 - RestSharp.dll 
 - RestSharp.xml
 - WindowsApp1.exe 
 - WindowsApp1.exe.config 
 - WindowsApp1.pdb
 - WindowsApp1.xml
```

Do I need to move some to the Win10 test system and register some of them?

This is my first VS application and I'm finding it to be very complicated as compared to VB6, but such is progress I guess.

I really appreciate any advise or wisdom or help here.

Comment: This is not an "Answer", and so you should not post it here. Also: Windows XP is fully end of life. It has not received any patches for several years now... _not even critical security updates_; it's not okay for **anyone** to still be using it. Leaving XP users behind won't be an issue. In fact, it's so old that Vista & Windows 7 are in the same boat, and also no longer receive patches. At least for Windows 7 this is fairly recent and there are (to date so far) only two known significant missing security issues, both of which still have work-arounds. It won't stay that way much longer, though

Comment: Thanks Joel.  I have no control over what Windows OS my customers use.  I've been trying to maintain XP compat just for that reason.  That being said, there are probably none using XP at this time.
I put the remark into the comment area and noticed that I was way over the character limit.  So I copied it and put it into an answer, then finished the remark.  Should I have used two comment boxes?  Seems more complicated but maybe the system is looking for that structure for some reason.

Comment: Can you please copy this information and add it to your question, then delete this as it is not an answer.